# Two's complement proof

Tags: math, proof, twos-complement

Is it possible to prove by induction that the two's complement of any string of 0's will always result in 0, for all sequences of length n?

I'm trying to do this using the value formula, i.e.

value = -a_n-1 x 2^(n-1) + summation{i=0 to n} (a_i x 2^i), where n = number of bits in string

Comment: belongs on mathoverflow/math.SE?

Comment: You may be mixing up one's complement and two's complement.

Comment: *Pet peeve:* [ **Ones'** complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) (to one comment and one answer, and before more people get on one's cranky side ;)

Comment: Definitely does *not* belong on MO. Conceivably on M.SE if, you know, it were correct. But two's complement is almost exclusively a computing notion, so it doesn't seem out of place here.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the 2's complement of **111..111** just **1** (which means that 111..111 represents -1)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking to prove that, for example, the two's complement of `1111 1111` is `0000 0000`? If so, you can not prove it because it is false. The two's complement of `1111 1111` is `0000 0001`.

```
    1111 1111
->  0000 0000 <- one's complement
->  0000 0001 <- add 1
```

Response to your edit: Sure. But you don't need induction. Inverting all of the bits of `0_n` to obtain the one's complement gives you `1_n` and adding `1` flips all the bits back to zero (`1 + 1  = 10` and the carry bit percolates through to end where we drop it). QED.

Comment: Sorry, meant string of 0's. For example, 0000 => flipping bits and adding 1 will yield 1111 + 1 = 0000 with a 1 carry that is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

1) Definition of two complement of X: flip the bits of X and sum 1

2) Binary sum of two variables with 1 bit (http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/adder.html) (being b1 the first variable and b2 the second variable. b1:X denote bit X in the variable)

```
r1 = b1:1 XOR b2:1
carry = b1:1 AND b2:1
```

2.1) if both bits are one b1:1 and b2:1

```
r1 = 0  (always)
carry = 1 (always)
```

3) Binary sum of two variables with 2 bit

```
r1 = b1:1 XOR b2:1 
carry1 = b1:1 AND b2:1

r2 = (b1:2 XOR b2:2) XOR carry:1
carry2 = (b1:2 AND b2:2) OR (b1:2 AND carry:1) OR (b2:2 AND carry:1)
```

3.1) From 2.1 we can reduce

```
carry2 = (b1:2 AND b2:2) OR (b1:2 AND 1) OR (b2:2 AND 1)
carry2 = b1:2 OR b2:2
```

4) Be a number Zero all zeros. Flipping all bits will generate an all ones number: Ones

5) Bit 0 XOR Anything = Anything (truth table of XOR)

6) Applying (1) on number Zero

6.1) flip

```
 Flipping Zero = Ones
```

6.2) sum 1

```
 result = Ones + N_One (N_One = 00...001)
 result:1 = 0 (from 2.1)
 carry:1 = 1 (from 2.1)
```

6.3) As all bits from N_One except N_One:1 are zero.

```
 result:n = (Ones:n XOR N_One:n) XOR carry:(n-1) (from 3)
 result:n = (Ones:n XOR 0) XOR carry:(n-1) (definition of N_One 6.2)
 result:n = Ones:n XOR carry:(n-1)
```

6.4) from 3.1

```
carry:n = Ones:n OR N_One:n -> if carry:n-1 is 1
carry:n = 1 OR 0            -> if carry:n-1 is 1
carry:n = 1                 -> if carry:n-1 is 1
```

As the first carry (carry:1) is defined as 1 from 6.1 all carries are defined as 1

7) from 6.3 and 6.4

```
 result:n = Ones:n XOR carry:(n-1)
 result:n = 1 XOR 1
 result:n = 0
```

For any value of n, proving that (~n+1) is always 0. (the last carry for a machine with fixed bitfield size is always ignored)

QED